# error while creating a function similar to strcmp()

Tags: c, string, function

I created a function that works like strcmp() - called compareString. First if else condition checks if two strings are of equal length. The for loop checks if each element of array a and b are equal and it stops after whole string is checked [ by condition i the if condition should check till countString(a)-1

```
bool compareString(char a[],char b[])
{
    if(countString(a)==countString(b)) //i had made a function countString that works as strlen
    {
        int i;
        printf("%d\n",countString(a));
       for(i=0;a[i]==b[i]&&i<countString(a);i++) {};
       if(i==countString(a)-1) return 1; //*********line1*******// 
       else return 0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

as in the condition of for loop i have mentioned i

Comment: Is your question incomplete? I don't see an actual question or description of what problem you are having. Or are you getting a compile error? Because there is a typo: `{)` should be `{}`.

Comment: I created a function that works like strcmp() - called compareString. First if else condition checks if two strings are of equal length. The for loop checks if each element of array a and b are equal and it stops after whole string is checked [ by condition i the if condition should check till countString(a)-1 as in the condition of for loop i have mentioned i<countString(a). But the program gives correct output when i write i==countString(a) on line1. This dosen't make sense as i have given the condition of less than.

Comment: Please put that into the question. And what exactly do you mean by "correct output"? Please provide exact input, expected output and actual output. And you really need to provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code.

Comment: There was some character limit i guess , so the whole question was not visible. By correct output i meant when i compare two same strings it returned 0 with condition `countString(a)-1` in the if statement. But when i put condition `countString(a)` in if statement, the two similar strings returned 1. So i wanted to ask if `if(i==countString(a)-1)` this condition that i have applied is correct or not. @kaylum

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs some restructuring.

```cpp
bool compareString(char a[], char b[]) {
    // strings not the same length, return false
    if (countString(a) != countString(b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    // we call this before the loop so we don't call it multiple times
    int len = countString(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
        // strings have differing characters, return false
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // we haven't returned false yet so they're the same
    return 1;
}
```

Remember that when you call `return`, the code stops running immediately and exits out of the function.

Comment: "Remember that when you call return". What is the point you are trying to make there? Are you implying that the OP has a `return` in the wrong place? Which one? Admittedly your version is more efficient, but IMHO we don't actually know what the OP's actual problem is yet.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, but it's referencing the fact that I call `return` in my code to avoid an else statement and to break out of the for loop, so I thought it was important to state what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The logic that should be used is
1.Read two Strings 
2.Obtain the length of both the strings
3.If 
     Length of two strings are not equal then return mismatch 
  else 
     Compare character by character of both strings
                     * if character not same
                        Return mismatch 
                    * else
                         Return string matches